# Restore Building in Minecraft PE

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I want to build a structure where the player will flip a switch and create a TNT explosion potentially dropping them into lava, but I want to be able to restore the structure without having to completely re-build it by hand so it can be played again.  Sorry I'm a newbie all help is appreciated.

Comment: Is there any research or things you've tried that you can share with us?  You'll find that the users here are more likely to help you if can show that you've put some effort into solving your own problem first.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using it in creative mode with cheats on you can build an identical build elsewhere and use the clone command to replace it. I can't give you an exact command with all the tags available because I don't know the coordinates and the size of your structure. If you have already built the structure try cloning it elsewhere and set up a command block that clones it and hook it up to a clock that does it every minute or something along those lines. If you are not using cheats or not in creative mode then you can't do anything about it.